# pandas dataframe match string in any place( column name or any cell)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So far  found  there is a way to match string in particular column using  `df['A'].str.contains(re.compile("[Dd]ate"))`.  This is a way to find column A contains "date" or "Date".

How about any place in this dataframe, including column names or any cell?
Return True if any column names or cell contains this pattern, else False
.

Comment: What is your expected return from this?  Secondly, you don't need to user re.compile, contains accepts a regex str.    `df['A'].str.contains('[Dd]ate')` will work also.

Comment: maybe `'date' in df.to_string().lower()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the whole df (including row and column indices) to a string and then search that string:

```
re.search('[Dd]ate', df.to_string()) != None
```